# GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut() does not sign out user

Tags: ios, google-signin

I am following the google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift).

There is no sign out button so I created a custom button, and wired it up to:

```
@IBAction func didTapSignOut(sender: AnyObject) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
}
```

But this method does not trigger the `GIDSignInDelegate` method: 
`func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)`

Comment: This method works and triggers the delegate function `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()`

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is a way to report this fix? There seems to be no feedback button here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in